# Homogenous polynomial and partial derivatives

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I'm struggling to understand this part in a book I'm reading:

> Let $F$ be a projective curve of degree $d$ with $P\in F$. Wlog,
>   suppose $P=(a:b:1)$. Let's look the affine chart $(a,b)\mapsto
>  (a,b,1)$.
>
> Let $f$ be the deshomogenization of $F$, we can write $f$ in this way:
>   **(WHY?)**
>
> $$f=F(x,y,1)=f_1(x-a,y-b)+\ldots +f_d(x-a,y-b)$$
>
> Where $f_l$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $l$ and we have
>   **(WHY?)**
>
> $$f_l=\sum_{i+j=l}\frac{1}{i!j!}\frac{\partial^lf}{\partial^ix\partial^jy}x^iy^j$$

I know this should be a silly question, but I'm a beginner in this subject and I really need help, if anyone could help me I would be grateful.

Thanks

**EDIT**

I'm thinking about Taylor's formula, but The formula of the post doesn't match with the Taylor's  one of several variables, see for example this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables), maybe there is some mistake in the formula of my post?

Comment: $F$ is already homogeneous. you mean $f$ is the dehomogenization of $F$.

Comment: and to see the identity, give yourself a few examples. Take $f=x+3xy+y^3$. Decompose it into its homogeneous parts: $x$ of degree 1, $3xy$ of degree 2, and $y^3$ of degree $3$. Does it satisfy the above identity? so you need to express the coefficients of a polynomial in terms of its partial derivatives.

Comment: @abdrido yes, I'm sorry, thank you for the remark

Comment: @abdrido Take for example $(a,b)=(1,2)$ In the first equality, we have $f_1(x1,y-2)= x-1$, $f_2(x-1,y-2)=3(x-1)(y-2)$ and $(y-2)^3$, I don't have the first equality, because $f\neq f_1(x-1,y-2)+f_2(x-1,y-2)+f_3(x-1,y-2)$

Comment: but f does not vanish at $(a,b)=(1,2)$. You need to have $f(a,b)=F(a,b,1)=0$. pick a point for which this holds and you will have equality

Comment: @abdrido yes, you're right. Now, I took $(a,b)=(-1/4,1)$ $f$ vanishes at this point, but If I made the correct calculations we had $f_1(x+1/4,y-1)+f_2(x+1/4,y-1)+f_3(x+1/4,y-1)=-2x+3xy-3/2+y^3+3/4y-3y^2+3y\neq f(x,y)$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: I can't check right now, but probably you are doing sth wrong in evaluating the derivatives. this identity is really just saying that the taylor series expansion is exact for a polynomial. so if you compute the partial derivates at (-1/4,1) and then multiply by (x+1/4)^i(y-1)^j you should get back the same thing. maybe try with sth simpler like $f=x^2+yx-2$ at $(1,1)$

Comment: dear @abdrido this formula doesn't match with the Taylor formula of several variables, see for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables, maybe there is some mistake in the formula of my post?

Answer (score 1):

User @adrido basically answered this question in the comments, but I thought I'd elaborate more fully, in case anyone encounters this in the future.

The polynomial $f$ consists of a a number of *homogeneous parts* - these are the collections of terms of $f$ which all have the same degree:
$$
\underbrace{x^3y^2 - x^5}_{\deg 5} + \underbrace{3x^2y^2 + 9y^4}_{\deg 4} + \underbrace{2xy^2 - 7x^3 + 15y^3}_{\deg 3} + \cdots
$$
The big question here is what on earth does this have to do with all those partial derivatives? You're right, it's not a Taylor series, but it's sorta the same idea.

By taking the $\ell$-th partial derivatives of a polynomial $f$ and evaluating it at $0$, what we're left with is the coefficients of the degree $\ell$ terms (the partial derivatives cause all $k<\ell$ degree terms to vanish, and all higher degree terms vanish when we evaluate at $0$), but the coefficients are multiplied by $i!j!$ where $i+j = \ell$. Indeed, you can check for yourself that for any polynomial $f(x, y)$, the coefficient of $x^iy^j$ in $f$ (which we will denote $[x^iy^j]f(x, y)$ is given by
$$
[x^iy^j]f(x, y) = \frac1{i!j!}\frac{\partial^{i+j}f}{\partial x^i\partial y^j}(0, 0)
$$
So we can reconstruct $f$ using these coefficients we've just obtained:
$$
f = \sum_{i,j}\left([x^iy^j]f\right)x^iy^j = \sum_{i,j}\left(\frac1{i!j!}\frac{\partial^{i+j}f}{\partial x^i\partial y^j}(0, 0)\right)x^iy^j
$$
I suppose what's nice about this decomposition is it collects up the homogeneous parts of $f$ as those terms above for which $i+j$ is constant, equal to some $\ell$.

Of course, everything above generalizes to a polynomial $f(x_1, ..., x_n)$, but I leave it to you to work out the (messy, but straightforward) details.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** "I know this should be a silly question, but I'm a beginner in this subject and I really need help, if anyone could help me I would be grateful. Thanks"

**Answer:** When trying to prove a formula you should verify the formula in an explicit "elementary " example first, then try to generalize.

**Example:** Let $F:=x^2+y^2+z^2$ and let $p:=(a,b,1) \in D(z)$ with $u:=x/z, v:=y/z$ local coordinates. Let $f(u,v):=u^2+v^1+1$.

It follows

$$f(u,v)=f(a+u-a, b+v-b)=(a+u-a)^2+(b+v-b)^2+1= $$

$$a^2+b^2+1+ 2a(u-a)+2b(v-b)+(u-a)^2+(v-b)^2=$$

$$=f(a,b)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial_u}(a,b)(u-a)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}(a,b)(v-b) + $$

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u^2}(a,b)(u-a)^2 +\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial u \partial v}(a,b)(u-a)(v-b)+\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial v^2}(a,b)(v-b)^2.$$

In general you get for any polynomial $g(u,v)$ the formula

$$g(u,v)=T_p(g(u,v)):=\sum_{k\geq 0} \sum_{i+j=k}\frac{\partial^{k} f}{\partial^i_u \partial^j_v}(a,b)(u-a)^i(v-b)^j,$$

which is the Taylor expansion of $g(u,v)$ at the point $p$.